# Granger causality over VECM (unknown possible problem in data)

Tags: econometrics, multicollinearity, vector-error-correction-model, granger-causality, macroeconomics

I have data with 4 variables GDP, foreign debt, export (all in nominal values), and exchange rate.

- Each of those are I(1) (the difference is stationary).
- The four variables together are cointegrated (there is at least linear correlation of those which is stationary).
- Johansen cointegration test suggests a significant long-run relationship with theoretical correct signs.
- When we use the Vector error correction model most of the lag coefficients are insignificant.
- Granger causality test indicates

  1. a bidirectional causal relationship between GDP and exchange rate (which is reasonable);
  2. a unidirectional relationship from GDP to export (also may be reasonable);
  3. a unidirectional causality from debt to export (which also makes sense);
  4. there is no causality between GDP and export neither direction (which puts 1. in the shade since in particular it indicates that the causality in 1. is not result of the export).

There was a doubt that there was multicollinearity between variables, for instance- between export and exchange rate but the correlation table suggests there is high correlation between debt and export but not between export and exchange rate, which is disappointing.

On this ground, I try to exclude export, exchange rate, or debt. The resulting systems of three variables became non-integrated and the appropriate statistics also have shown strange results.

Does anyone have any idea what might be a problem in data and what to look at to figure out a problem? Some appropriate statistical methods, models, or references on similar problems will be appreciated.

Comment: Please use capital letters where appropriate.

Comment: @RichardHardy +